# matlab show the figure and update the text of the uicontrol

Tags: matlab, figure, matlab-figure

**After 6 hours, I solved my problem! :]**

> `this was my question:`

please help me: how can I show the figure when the function 'GUI_400' is called?

In addition, I want the text of 'S.ty' to be updated by the numbers between 1 to 100.
In order to do this, I called the 'test' function and updated the uicontrol of s.ty.

in other words, show the figure and only update the text of 'S.ty' with number of '1', then in number of '2'... till 100.

in my code, the figure is shown when the 'test' function ends and that's why the figure will be showed only with the number '100'.

Comment: Maybe you need some sort of delay? It might be showing each figure, just too fast to see each one.

Comment: @kevlar1818, I don't think I want the delay :/ I prefer other solution. thank you :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function [] = GUI_400()

    hFig = figure('units','pixels',...
        'position',[300 300 424 430],...
        'menubar','none',...
        'name','GUI_3',...
        'numbertitle','off',...
        'resize','off');        

        Im = imread('0.png');
        hAxes = axes('Parent',hFig,'Units','pixels','Position',[0 72 424 359]);  %#   so the position is easy to define
        image(Im,'Parent',hAxes);  %# Plot the image
        set(hAxes,'Visible','off', 'handlevisibility', 'off');          %# Turn the axes visibility off

        S.tx = uicontrol('style','text',...
         'unit','pix',...
         'position',[0 32 424 40],...
         'string','מכין תמונה 1 מתוך 3',...
         'backgroundcolor','r',...
         'fontsize',23);
        mystr = 'alon';
         temp = uicontrol('style','text',...
         'unit','pix',...
         'position',[0 0 424 40],...
         'string',mystr,...
         'backgroundcolor','r',...
         'fontsize',23);

   for i = 1:1000
        set(temp,'string',num2str(i));
       drawnow;
   end
end
```